# Do I have to have the actual instructions on a cloning potion to make one?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm trying to get the rocket boots, which are apparently in the room in the desert castle that has a chest too high to reach.

I read something online where a guy made clones of himself and then climbed them to get to the chest. I don't have the actual instructions on how to make the cloning potion, but can I still brew it? I don't want to waste candies on something that might not even work.

Also, is there another, easier way to get to the chest? If so, that would *really* help.

Comment: Doesn't the single recipe book and the ability to make potions come at the exact same time?

Comment: yeah, I thought so too, but I don't have the cloning potion instructions in my cauldron's recipe book... I don't know what to think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the concept of the clone is a good idea but it takes too much cloning potions.  Instead use a summoning tribe spear.  It is the same concept but it is faster and it doesn't cost anything

Comment: @happycamper21 You might want to consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.